# Exclude template reference and macros from document

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, word-2007

I am creating a template which has some macros inside. What the macros do is to open a user form which will prompt the user for some information which will then go into the new document.

The problem is that once the new document is created, it still somehow have a reference to this template and the macro code.

I have to send the document to people outside of the organization and they get a warning that the document contains macros.

Is there a way to avoid this? I want the document to be created without any of the macros or referrence to the original template.

Comment: Is the new document being created off of your template? You should post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the new document with "Normal" as a parameter for the [Documents.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845011.aspx) method. The default seems to be to create a document off of the current open template (or Normal if none).